# Dojo DataGrid choosing correct store for BigDecimal[][] object

Tags: java, datagrid, store, dojo

I am trying to implement the dojo DataGrid component.

I have a BigDecimal[][] object that I would like to use as the store.

I am just not sure what store to use.

I thought the CsvStore would work but it failed to load any data.

I could use the JsonRestStore but my grid only needs to be loaded initially and I would have to go back to my service class and format my current BigDecimal[][] object into some kind of `List<SomeNewObject>` object.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify how would you like to use the BigDecimal[][] data? For example, if the BigDecimal[][] is a 4 * 5 array, will you like the grid to have 4 rows and 5 columns respectively? Or you have a list of BigDecimal[][] data and each BigDecimal[][] is just a row in the grid?

Comment: I have a list of BigDecimal[].  Each BigDecimal[] has 6 BigDecimal fields in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` is OK for you. Suppose your BigDecimal[][] looks like:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 1] 
]
```

You can create a `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` using:

```
var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({
    items : [
        {col1 : 1, col2 : 2, col3 : 3, col4 : 4, col5 : 5, col6 : 6},
        {col1 : 3, col2 : 4, col3 : 5, col4 : 3, col5 : 5, col6 : 1}
    ]
});
```